# best approach to refine search in Lift?

Tags: lift

I need to render a list of objects which can be dynamically refined on some variables. As for example change the  order of the items. An example can be: https://www.airbnb.it/s/California

A possibility is:

- Build  a REST API according to the variables for the refinement;
- Use SHtml for embedding UI refinement elements  and fire a Js function;
- Write a Js function which calls the REST API and renders the HTML;

Are there other solutions?
An advantage is that I will use REST API for developing on Tablet/Smarthpone.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is strike balance. At best pull all data using REST API (json/xml) parse it and store on client side. When time comes refinement should work on client side if possible and if necessary pull more data from server. So in your case I'd stick to REST API for pulling data then client side should take care of rendering. It is slightly more complex but pays off in longer term. Also if you wan't to create mobile app then you need API to call. Using REST API you can refactor your code so both Lift generated html/js and API call same core functions and benefit from code reuse.